# WPF inherited UserControl lost VS designer support

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2008, inheritance, designer

I' written this UserControl:

```
<my:MyUserControl x:Class="MyClass"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"             
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:my="clr-namespace:MyNameSpace.MyControls;assembly=MyAssembly">
 </my:MyUserControl>

 public partial class Editor : MyNameSpace.MyControls.MyUserControl {}
```

Everything works, the control is shown in the VS 2008 Designer, but I cannot click directly in the elements and select them as it was with `UserControl`.

Any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I know why is that.

It really works, but My base class was implementing an `IComponent` interface, which was a reason of the loss of designer support.

```
public class BaseClass: System.Windows.Controls.UserControl, System.ComponentModel.IComponent
{}
```

If I **delete the Interface**, it works again !